# Proper usage of Schedulers

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to read a file from the file system, update a room database and update the UI in the end. This seems a particularly simple task but I'm struggling with proper usage of Android  and RxJava Schedulers.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    this.loadingTextView = this.findViewById(R.id.tvLoading);

    this.subscription = Observable.just(0)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(ignore -> engine.checkEngineRequirements())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(ignore-> Log.e("glog", "Received on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()),
                    throwable -> Log.e("glog", "[WelcomeActivity.onCreate()]:" + throwable.getMessage()),
                    () -> {
                        this.loadingTextView.setText("Loaded");
                        Log.d("glog", "[WelcomeActivity] Launching new activity");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayGameActivity.class);
                        this.startActivity(intent);
                    }
            );
}
```

In checkEngineRequirements I'm loading files from a file and populating a room database:

```
private Observable<Long> checkEngineRequirements() {
    return new OfflineDataLoad().load(this.context)                
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(data -> this.dataRepository.addData(data));
}

public Observable<String> load(Context context) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            context.getAssets().open(DB_FILE_NAME), "UTF-8"));
            (...)
            while (lineAvailabe) {
                emitter.onNext(line)
            }
            emitter.onComplete();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
        }
    });
}
```

My datasource (repository) is implemented as follows:

```
@Override
public Observable<Long> addData(Data newDataItem) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> this.dataDao.insertData(newDataItem));
}
```

The problem is that the onComplete event is never called. Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Either you have an error (should be in the log) or the `subscription` gets disposed and thus the subscribe callbacks are never invoked. Add a `doOnDispose` before the last `subscribe` and log there too.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd ! *onDispose* event is called and no error is shown in logs.

Answer (score 1):

*Based on the comments:*

The general way of troubleshooting sequences is to use the `doOnXXXX` operators and log the various events.

In this case, the flow described did not imply any infinite sequences (as it is a very common with Room queries) and did nothing particularly complicated. Thus what remained is the stored `subscription` variable and the fact that the main part of the code runs in the background when started from within `onCreate` on the main thread and may *eventually* return to the main thread again.

This gives an ample time for the UI to get destroyed, and with it, the aforementioned `subscription` disposed. To be sure, of course, applying `doOnDispose()` with logging as close to the end consumer should and has revealed that indeed this is the case:

```java
this.subscription = Observable.just(0)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap(ignore -> engine.checkEngineRequirements())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        // v---------------------------------v-----------------------------------v----
        .doOnDispose(() -> Log.e("glog", "[WelcomeActivity.onCreate()]: Disposed"))
        // ^---------------------------------^-----------------------------------^--
        .subscribe(ignore-> Log.e("glog", "Received on thread " 
                     + Thread.currentThread().getName()),
                throwable -> Log.e("glog", "[WelcomeActivity.onCreate()]:" 
                     + throwable.getMessage()),
                () -> {
                    this.loadingTextView.setText("Loaded");
                    Log.d("glog", "[WelcomeActivity] Launching new activity");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayGameActivity.class);
                    this.startActivity(intent);
                }
        );
```

Comment: I might have found what happened.
I was disposing the subscription on onStop event of Activity lifecycle. Now, my doubt is when to dispose the subscription correctly.